# Redirect a forbidden URL in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to move an entire directory and its subdirectories from one Apache server A to another Apache server B, and then create a redirection from A to B.

i.e.

`http://server_a.com/docroot/dir` to `http://server_b.com/docroot/dir`.

This is what I did:

1. I copied the files and directory structure under `dir` from A to B
2. I deleted the directory `dir` on A
3. I created a rule in `docroot/.htaccess` on server A that reads

`Redirect permanent dir/ http://server_b.com/docroot/dir/`

But when I go to `http://server_a.com/docroot/dir/path/to/file/index.html`, I get a 403 Forbidden, even if the target page `http://server_b.com/docroot/dir/path/to/file/index.html` is up.

I know that the `.htaccess` is read by Apache, because it correctly controls other parts of `server_a`. I am not root on these servers. I have also tried with a `RewriteRule`, with the exact same results.

How should I go about creating a redirect in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mod_rewrite enabled than you can do this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?docroot/dir(/.*)?$ http://server_b.com/docroot/dir$1 [R=301,L]
```

Put it in your .htaccess file in the Document Root directory `http://server_a.com/`.

#### Note:

Delete you Browser cache first.

Comment: This solution works. I also modified the flags for `[NC,R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the leading `/` in the old URL. Like this:

`Redirect permanent "/dir" "http://server_b.com/docroot/dir/"`

See the [mod_alias docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) for more details.

Comment: Do you access the current site from `http://server_a.com/docroot/dir` or `http://server_a.com/dir`? Is `docroot` part of the URL?

Comment: No, `docroot` is not part of the url.